# What is the proper name for validating the strings in Excel Formula?

Tags: windows, excel

I want to know about the name of validating the formulas. i.e,

if i give wrong arguments for one formula **(=SUM(sample))**, it will return result as **"#NAME"**. Here i want to know about the name of this validation.

What would be the name of this process?

- Formula Validation (or)
- Error String Validation (or)
- Formula Error String Validation

Can you suggest me the better name of this method?

Answer (score 0):

I would it call name validation because here `sample` is assumed as [Name](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64).

`SUM` needs values or references as parameters. References can either be normal cell references like `A1` or `Sheet1!A1` or [Structured Table References](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) or [Names](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64).

In this case `sample` is assumed to be a name. So Excel will search the name in defined names. It will not find it. So it returns `#NAME?` error value.

If you ask about the general process, then this is called [Formula evaluation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59A201AE-D1DC-4B15-8586-A70AA409B8A7?CorrelationId=4d75637d-3fc4-4f0d-ad75-37592006e4f9&ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ). This formula evaluation either results in a value or an error value like `#NAME?`, `#VALUE!`, `#DIV/0!` ...

Comment: Thanks. There are many cases, like #VALUE, #NUM!. Can you suggest me the generic method name?